# yeoman : yo command hangs forever

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I started following this tutorial :
http://mobileangularui.com/blog/using-the-generator/
after one day of resolving errors and dependencies, now I am stuck as my yeoman since I didn´t found any answer or a similar case on the Internet!

when I try the "yo mobileangularui" it displays :

```
 _-----_
|       |    .--------------------------.
|--(o)--|    |     Welcome to Mobile    |
---------    |  Angular Ui Boilerplate  |
( _´U`_ )    |        generator!        |
/___A___\    '--------------------------'
 |  ~  |
```

and it hangs here forever without promping for the app name

Knowing that I am running Windows 10, any help ?

When I stop it manually I get this :

```
Error: write EINVAL
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
at MuteStream.ondata (stream.js:31:26)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at MuteStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
readline.js:991
        throw err;
        ^

Error: This socket is closed
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:683:19)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Console.log (console.js:43:16)
    at module.exports.UI.onForceClose (C:\Users\Wail\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\node_modules\inquirer\lib\ui\baseUI.js:32:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're running into a bug released in Node 7.1.0 https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542

My suggestion is to downgrade to Node 7.0 until they released a patched version.

Comment: perfect answer, I uninstalled node 7.1.0 and retried with the current LTS version 6.9.1 and it's works!

Comment: Having the same problem with a different generator with node version 10...